# Finding the probability of the product of two RV

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be independent binomial random variables with $X_i$ having parameters $\left(n_i,p_i\right),\,i=1,2$. Find $\mathrm{Pr}\left(X_1X_2=0\right)$.

It is not very clear to me how to approach this problems. I am aware that if the random variables are independent then $\mathrm{Pr}\left(X_1=x_1,\,X_2=x_2\right)=\mathrm{Pr}\left(X_1=x_1\right)\mathrm{Pr}\left(X_2=x_2\right)$. I cannot see how the product of the two rv can be $0$.

Comment: You write that you cannot see how the product $X_1X_2$ can be 0, but it happens if and only if at least one is zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P\{X_1X_2=0\}=P(\{X_1=0\} \cup \{X_2=0\})=P(\{X_1=0\}+P(\{X_2=0\}-P(\{X_1=0\} \cap \{X_2=0\})=(1-p_1)^{n}+(1-p_2)^{n}-(1-p_1)^{n}(1-p_2)^{n}$.